# How to implement dynamic objects with LLVM?

Tags: object, hashmap, llvm

Assuming a javascript-like language, how can we implement a system such as:

```
a = {};
a.foo = {};
a.foo.bar = 42;
print a.foo['bar'];
```

using LLVM C++ API ?

I didn't find any documentation about complexe data types (such as an HashMap heriting from Value), so I'm kind of lost here. The LLVM C demo webpage isn't useful neither, as there is no such data type in C/C++.

I've done the Kaleidoscope tutorial, but didn't found any other really good tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the same way as you'll do it on top of any other low level semantics. You have to implement your own runtime library, your own hash maps (or whatever else you'd like to use for the dynamic dispatch). LLVM does not (and should not) provide any runtime for the code it generates.

Comment: Can I use C++ as language for the runtime library ? Or should I write it using llvm intermediate representation ? Have you got any link about this ? I'm not sure about the way to ship this library

Comment: @NisonMaël, of course you can link to any of the existing libraries, including libstdc++ - but in your case it will be quite an overkilll. You'll have to implement a large part of C++ ABI, especially mangling, in order to just use a couple of library functions. The simplest way would be to implement your library in C and link it statically or dynamically, whatever you like. Another approach (although I would not recommend it in your case) is to implement LLVM intrinsics.

Comment: P.S., one way to use C++ for implementing your runtime library would be to wrap its API into `extern "C"`

Comment: I think I see what you means. Are you aware of any article talking about designing this kind of library in order to integrate it with llvm (even for other data types such as a string container) ? Having an example would be greatly appreciated ''

Comment: @NisonMaël, I do not know of any articles on this topic, but you can take a look at VMkit and at the Pure language. The latter is quite simple, with a compact and easy to understand runtime.

Answer (score 2):

An example of a *jit language* written in python with llvm is here [link to a student project](http://llvm.cs.uiuc.edu/pubs/2009-05-21-Thesis-Barrett-3c.html).
It's not directly what you need but it is object oriented and the report covers a simple  methodology for implementing the object orientation of a language.

Comment: The link to the student paper is broken

Comment: Yes, have to -1 while the link doesn't work.

Comment: https://llvm.org/pubs/2009-05-21-Thesis-Barrett-3c.pdf